# Why is this $elemMatch query not using my index?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-indexes

My query:

```
{
    "unique_contact_method.enrichments": {
        "$not": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "created_by.name": "fullcontact"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Index:

```
{
    v: 1,
    name: "unique_contact_method.enrichments.created_by.name_1",
    key: {
        "unique_contact_method.enrichments.created_by.name": 1
    },
    ns: "app27434806.unique_contact_methods",
    background: true,
    safe: true
}
```

The .explain() result:

[image]

Why no index?

Comment: Please add a sample document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the [**`$not`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) operator here is what makes index usage impossible. There is one statement in the documentation that "implies" this, if not completely clearly:

> *"Remember that the $not operator only affects other operators and cannot check fields and documents independently. So, use the $not operator for logical disjunctions and the $ne operator to test the contents of fields directly."*

The essential phrase there is "cannot check fields", which means it does not actually "test" the value of the field as can be done with an index. A simple document explains this the best:

```js
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("53f3e414deee3a78e47e57e2"), 
    "created" : [ { "name" : "Bill" }, { "name" : "Ted" } ]
}
```

Where of course an index is created on "created.name".

Now consider the following query and explain output:

```js
db.doctest.find({ "created": { "$elemMatch": { "name": "Bill" } } }).explain()

{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor created.name_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "created.name" : [
                    [
                            "Bill",
                            "Bill"
                    ]
            ]
    },
    "server" : "ubuntu:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

That simply selects the index and shows the index bounds as expected.

Not look at this with `$not`, and I'm going to "force" the index with `.hint()`:

```js
db.doctest.find({ "created": { "$not": { "$elemMatch": { "name": "Bill" } } } }).hint({ "created.name": 1 }).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor created.name_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 2,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "created.name" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            },
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ]
    },
    "server" : "ubuntu:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

The important part to look at here is "indexBounds". This explains why without the hint the index would not be used, as simply put there are no "bounds" to select by. The `$not` operation basically says:

> *"Look at every value tested by the condition and if it is true then consider it false or essentially the reverse"*

The end evaluation here is that "Ted" is not "Bill" therefore the condition is true, but there is no way to "look for that" using an index.

So the consideration here is how do you do the same thing and use an index? The passage from the documentation tells you that in order to consider the "field" you need to use the [**`$ne`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) operator instead:

```js
db.doctest.find({ "created": { "$elemMatch": { "name": { "$ne": "Bill" } } } }).explain()
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor created.name_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 2,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
            "created.name" : [
                    [
                            {
                                    "$minElement" : 1
                            },
                            "Bill"
                    ],
                    [
                            "Bill",
                            {
                                    "$maxElement" : 1
                            }
                    ]
            ]
    },
    "server" : "ubuntu:27017",
    "filterSet" : false
}
```

Now the "indexBounds" shows you that the index is used to essentially "filter out" the values that were supplied. So the index is used to pull any other value than "Bill".

The conclusion here is that `$not` has it's logical uses, but in many cases what you actually want is `$ne` instead. Where `$not` must be applied, take into consideration that and index for the field values will not be used to make the comparison.

Comment: `db.doctest.find({ "created": { "$not": { "$elemMatch": { "name": "Bill" } } } })` is different to `db.doctest.find({ "created": { "$elemMatch": { "name": { "$ne": "Bill" } } } })`. The first returns true only every element's name isn't "Bill", the second returns true if there is one element whose name isn't "Bill". I think **$not** just does logical reverse, and only does once.

Comment: @Wizard true, but the point here was to demonstrate "why" an index is not being used and the different permutations that can use an index and those that cannot.

Comment: I also have the confusion as Jordan Feldstein. Since **$not** has strict syntax `{ field: { $not: { <operator-expression> } } }` - it explicitly works as `NOT { field: <operator-expression> }`, I guess, so why mongodb doesn't make an optimization for it to be able to use index? Maybe the permutations make it impossible as you said. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @NeilLunn: A Champion among answerers.

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally I find the index has been used in query automatically even though operator `$not` joins the action. It let me recall 
this question which also confused me on a long moment. I try on the new clue and find something different. And I think I find the answer finally. Welcome to everyone to comment here if find something else different.

## Run on mongo shell, V2.6.4

**Initialize data as below:**

```
> db.a.drop();  
false

> db.a.insert({_id:1, a:[1,2,3], b:[{x:1, y:2}, {x:4, y:4}], c:1});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.a.insert({_id:2, a:[4,2,3], b:[{x:1, y:2}, {x:4, y:4}], c:1});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.a.ensureIndex({a:1}, {name:"a"});
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
        "ok" : 1
}
> db.a.ensureIndex({"b.x":1}, {name:"bx"});
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 2,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 3,
        "ok" : 1
}
> db.a.ensureIndex({c:1}, {name:"c"});
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 3,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 4,
        "ok" : 1
}
> db.a.getIndexes();
[
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "test.a"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "a" : 1
                },
                "name" : "a",
                "ns" : "test.a"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "b.x" : 1
                },
                "name" : "bx",
                "ns" : "test.a"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "c" : 1
                },
                "name" : "c",
                "ns" : "test.a"
        }
]

> db.a.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "a" : [ 1, 2, 3 ], "b" : [ { "x" : 1, "y" : 2 }, { "x" : 2, "y" : 3 } ], "c" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, "a" : [ 4, 2, 3 ], "b" : [ { "x" : 1, "y" : 2 }, { "x" : 4, "y" : 4 } ], "c" : 1 }
```

---

**This block just simply proves that index will be properly used automatically even though `$not` joins the query action.**

```
> db.a.find({c:{$not:{$gte:1}}}).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor c",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
        "nscanned" : 1,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "c" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                1
                        ],
                        [
                                Infinity,
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "Duke-PC:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
```

---

**This is the style that the original question mentioned. Index has been used automatically.**

```
> db.a.find({b:{$elemMatch:{x:{$gte:1}}}}).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor bx",            // attention on this line
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 2,
        "nscannedObjects" : 2,
        "nscanned" : 4,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 4,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 9,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "b.x" : [
                        [
                                1,
                                Infinity
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "Duke-PC:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
```

**Index doesn't work when use operator `$not` preceding `$elemMatch`. It's the core of this question.**

```
> db.a.find({b:{$not:{$elemMatch:{x:{$gte:1}}}}}).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",           // attention on this line
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 2,
        "nscanned" : 2,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "server" : "Duke-PC:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
```

---

**This block: find some way to explain the mechanics of index on array filed.**
Totally two documents, but `nscanned: 6`. This tells us something how the index has been structured on array type. That is, index node is on every element of array but not the array itself. I imagine the index structure on field `a` like this:
`BTree: Node(value:1, entry:[entry({_id:1})]), Node(value:2, entry:[entry({_id:1}), entry({_id:2})]), ...`
Of course, this is only my imagination for explanation. :)

```
> db.a.find({a:{$gte:1}}).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor a",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 2,
        "nscannedObjects" : 2,
        "nscanned" : 6,                 // attention on this line
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 6,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "a" : [
                        [
                                1,
                                Infinity
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "Duke-PC:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
```

---

**When use operator $not, the relevant index has been adopted automatically. And the field "indexBounds" tells us how `$not` handles the query.**

```
> db.a.find({a:{$not:{$gte:2}}},{_id:0,a:1}).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor a",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 0,
        "nscannedObjects" : 1,          // attention on this field
        "nscanned" : 2,                 // attention on this field
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 2,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {               // attention on this field
                "a" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                2
                        ],
                        [
                                Infinity,
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "Duke-PC:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
```

**Insert a new document with same field name `a` but not array.**

```
> db.a.insert({a:1});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.a.find();
{ "_id" : 1, "a" : [ 1, 2, 3 ], "b" : [ { "x" : 1, "y" : 2 }, { "x" : 2, "y" : 3 } ], "c" : 1 }
{ "_id" : 2, "a" : [ 4, 2, 3 ], "b" : [ { "x" : 1, "y" : 2 }, { "x" : 4, "y" : 4 } ], "c" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("541e4fcbb65042180c128280"), "a" : 1 }
```

**Please read this block comparing with just above content.**

```
> db.a.find({a:{$not:{$gte:2}}},{_id:0,a:1}).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor a",
        "isMultiKey" : true,        // This tells engine there are repeated array elements on index.
        "n" : 1,
        "nscannedObjects" : 2,      // The third document should only access the index to fetch data 
                                    // since it has enough information.
                                    // But here engine still read from the collection. My unstanding is the engine 
                                    // can not distinguish whether this index field is an array element or not, 
                                    // so it has to access the collection to find more information.
        "nscanned" : 3,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 3,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 25,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "a" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                2
                        ],
                        [
                                Infinity,
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "Duke-PC:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
```

**Conclusion:**

1. `elemMatch` is very special:

   - `$elemMatch` explicitly tells that the field "b" is an array.
   - And according to the query definition on this operator, any element found matching the query then `true` can be returned immediately. But only completing to scan all elements of the array and not finding any satisfying one, then `false` can be returned.
   - `But index structure (think about my imagination above) on array can not support this kind of operation because engine can not determine which nodes on index are exactly from a certain array, if only by index. This is the most important point to explain this question.`
2. Other operators have not this limit from their own query definition, such as $gte, $lt, ..., because only one matching can judge it's matched or not, which can be satisfied by index directly.

---

**Finally, there is a way to solve the original question, but not perfectly because the whole element must be provided.**
**Index on the array field, not the element.**

```
> db.a.ensureIndex({b:1});
{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 4,
        "numIndexesAfter" : 5,
        "ok" : 1
}
> db.a.find({b:{$ne:{x:2, y:3}}}).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor b_1",
        "isMultiKey" : true,
        "n" : 1,
        "nscannedObjects" : 2,
        "nscanned" : 4,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 2,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 4,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 33,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "b" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "x" : 2,
                                        "y" : 3
                                }
                        ],
                        [
                                {
                                        "x" : 2,
                                        "y" : 3
                                },
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "Duke-PC:27017",
        "filterSet" : false
}
```